# Do not understand part of how this sum was solved.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

I was given the following sum to solve:

> $E[t_n] =  \sum_{t = 1}^{n+1} t \cdot Pr(t_n = t)$
>   $= (n+1) \cdot (0.99)^n + 0.01 \cdot \sum_{t = 1}^{n} t \cdot (0.99)^{t - 1}  $

As well as the following solution to this sum:

> $ S = \sum_{t = 1}^{n}t \cdot 0.99^{t-1} = 1 + 2\cdot0.99+3\cdot0.99^2 + ... + n \cdot 0.99^{n - 1} $
>
> $ 0.99S = \sum_{t = 1}^{n}t \cdot 0.99^t = 1 \cdot 0.99 + 2\cdot0.99^2 +3\cdot0.99^3 + ... + (n-1) \cdot 0.99^{n - 1} + n \cdot 0.99^n $
>
> take the difference of the above two equations
>
> $ 0.01S = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} 0.99^i - n \cdot 0.99^n = \frac{1-0.99^n }{1-0.99} - n \cdot 0.99^n $
>   $ = 100 - (100 + n) \cdot 0.99^n $
>   where $\frac{1-0.99^n }{1-0.99}$ is the sum of a geometric series.

However, I do not understand what formula was used to solve the sum as well as how the following line was arrived at or what $i$ is:

> $ 0.01S = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} 0.99^i - n \cdot 0.99^n = \frac{1-0.99^n }{1-0.99} - n \cdot 0.99^n $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$S = 1 + 2\cdot 0.99 + 3 \cdot 0.99^2 + \dots + n \cdot 0.99^{n-1} $$
Multiplying by $0.99$ gives 
$$0.99S = 1\cdot 0.99 + 2 \cdot 0.99^2 + \dots + n \cdot 0.99^{n} $$
Now we're going to subtract the second equation from the first, combining the terms with the same power of $0.99$. This gives
$$ \begin{align}
S - 0.99S &= 1 + (2-1)\cdot 0.99 + (3-2)\cdot 0.99^2 + \dots + (n-(n-1))\cdot0.99^{n-1} - n\cdot 0.99^n \\
0.01S &= 1 + 1\cdot0.99 + 1\cdot0.99^2 + \dots + 1\cdot0.99^{n-1} - n\cdot 0.99^n
\end{align} $$
$i$ is just a placeholder variable to write all the terms on the right-hand side (except the last) in a single sum. These terms are a geometric series, and the solution you posted uses the formula for a sum of a geometric series and proceeds from there.

Comment: Why did we multiply by 0.99?  @Y.Forman?

Comment: @Paradox to allow us to line up the terms with the same power of $0.99$